# Reading Json data containing special symbols like curly braces, square brackets etc

Tags: java, getjson, json

I have json data saved as a string in a database. The structure of JSON data is fine with the problem that it contains regex expressions and even urls which contains curry braces {} or square brackets [] etc. I can replace  some of special symbols with the encodings available e.g hex or decimal encodings. and do string manipulations to take care of these. I was just wondering is there another way for handling this situation. I am getting following exception for the strings containing this type of Json data.

```
  org.json.JSONException: Expected a ',' or '}' at character 22891 of {"wires":[{"id"....so on
```

Please let me know if I need to elaborate more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the first thing coming to my mind:
When putting the thing in the database try php addslashes/stripslashes (assuming you are using php to contact the database).

Comment: Actually I am using java. And I have like 8000 rows of this data. Some of these rows will have such data. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Ohh, sorry, didn't read your first post carefully. In java it's usually achieved by use of PreparedStatement which will escape your strings automatically. Google it!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Can you elaborate more. Should I use PreparedStatement while inserting the data or getting the data from the database or in both conditions. What I read online looks like PreparedStatements are more helpful for performance purpose and few places also for escaping ' but I have data of {},[], & and even "".

Comment: I tried the PreparedStatment to access the database. But still I am getting same exceptions. I I try to parse the string on http://json.parser.online.fr/ it also shows error at those places which contain the such values

Comment: Problem seems to be lack of escaping. If you use escaping properly, you will be able to add {}. [], "" or any other character to the database and retrieve original value without any change. When testing it most importantly log what you are adding to DB and what you are getting and check if it's the same (otherwise JSON.parse will fail). I did a bit of reading and actually the way prepared statement is escaped depends on your database (arguments are send to db before substitution to statement) - check it's config. If all this fails you can always manually escape (substitute / with // etc).

Comment: I was able to fix by escaping " and /s. Thanks for your help.